# scanf function with list of numbers

Tags: c, loops, scanf

The program is supposed to read in digits one after the other to see if they are consecutive numbers or not. The second digit seems to be scanning as 21 all the time for some reason. Could anyone show me where i am going wrong? Thanks.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
 int a=1, e=1,n, digit1, compared;
 char y, z;

 scanf("n=%d, digits=%c%c", &n, &y, &z);

 digit1 = atoi(&y);
 compared = atoi(&z);

 if(digit1 == 0)
 {
  printf("False");
 }

 else if(compared == (digit1 + 1))
 {
  digit1++;

  for(a = 1;a < (n - 1);a++)
{
 scanf("%c", &z);
 compared = atoi(&z);

 if(compared == digit1 + 1)
  { 
   e++;
   digit1++;
  }
}

  if(e == (n - 1))
   {
    printf("True\n");
   }
  else
   {
    printf("False");
   }
 }

 else if(compared == (digit1 - 1))
 {
  digit1--;

  for(a = 1;a < (n - 1);a++)
  {
   scanf("%c", &z);
   compared = atoi(&z);

   if(compared == (digit1 - 1))
   {
    e++;
    digit1--;
   }
  }

 if(e == (n - 1))
 {
  printf("True\n");
 }

 else
 {
  printf("False");
 }
 }



 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do people not check the return value of `scanf`?

Comment: what is your input and output ?